# Instantiate Objects Automatically or with Iteration

Tags: powershell, class, iteration, instantiation

```
    class Molecule{
    [Int]$carbon
    [Int]$hydrogen
    [Int]$oxygen
}

$items = [ordered]@{
    water = [ordered]@{carbon = 0; hydrogen = 2; oxygen = 1}
    methane = [ordered]@{carbon = 1; hydrogen = 4; oxygen = 0}
    }
 
$EachKey1 = @() # Just for T-Shooting
$EachObj = @() # Just for T-Shooting
    
foreach ($key in $items.psbase.keys){
     $EachKey1 += $key
    $key = New-Object Molecule
     $EachObj += $key
    $key.carbon = $items.$key.carbon
    $key.hydrogen = $items.$key.hydrogen
    $key.oxygen = $items.$key.oxygen
}

""
$EachKey1 # Anticipated Values
$EachObj # Not getting values
```

######################### Output Below #########################

[image: Script Output]

Please assist with Instantiating Objects Automatically or via Iteration.

I am unable to instantiate Objects Water & Methane as attempted above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what your expected output would be, however, the clear mistake is in this line:

```
$key = New-Object Molecule
```

The item you're iterating over (the hash table **Key**) is getting replace by a new instance of the `Molecule` object, the when doing the **Property** assignment:

```
$key.carbon   = $items.$key.carbon
$key.hydrogen = $items.$key.hydrogen
$key.oxygen   = $items.$key.oxygen
```

You're effectively assigning `$null` to each **Property Value**, however, since your *class properties* are constrained to the type `[int]` PowerShell is converting `$null` to **0**:

```
[int] $null # => 0
```

If you want an array of `Molecule` objects you can simply do it this way:

```
$EachObj = foreach ($key in $items.PSBase.Keys) {
    [Molecule] $items[$key]
}
```

PowerShell converts the *ordered dictionary* into an instance of the class by *type casting* or [type conversion](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/understanding-powershells-type-conversion-magic/). The result would be the following:

```
PS /> $EachObj

carbon hydrogen oxygen
------ -------- ------
     0        2      1
     1        4      0

PS /> $EachObj[0] | Get-Member

   TypeName: Molecule

Name        MemberType Definition
----        ---------- ----------
Equals      Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method     type GetType()
ToString    Method     string ToString()
carbon      Property   int carbon {get;set;}
hydrogen    Property   int hydrogen {get;set;}
oxygen      Property   int oxygen {get;set;}
```

Type casting into an array of `Molecule` instances would also work:

```
PS /> $EachObj = [Molecule[]] $items[$items.PSBase.Keys]

PS /> $EachObj.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Molecule[]                               System.Array
```

Taking a step back, if your intent is to have an ordered dictionary with instances of your class as Values you could do it like this:

```
$items = [ordered]@{
    water   = [Molecule]@{ carbon = 0; hydrogen = 2; oxygen = 1 }
    methane = [Molecule]@{ carbon = 1; hydrogen = 4; oxygen = 0 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Knew that was were the problem was, but did not know how to approach it.  You are great!

Comment: This is great, but I am unclear on how to see which values are tied into which Molecule in $EachObj.  Do I need a dictionary for the result?

Comment: @colemd1 you mean you're unclear if the object you're seeing is _water_ or _methane_ and so on? If so, yes,  you could create a dictionary or maybe modify your class adding a new property (`$Type`) or similar. That's up to you

Comment: As always, your input is concise & invaluable!  I went with the $Type for now, as it fit my needs.  Never thought of making a variable equal the loop process and your technique on creating objects was new to me as well.  I will give Koans a try also.  If you know of any good sources for mastering looping techniques, please let me know.  :)

Comment: Just noticed the Step Back, that works great!  Did you just add that?  If not, sorry, was really tired last night.  Cheers!  :)

Comment: @colemd1 I guessed you were looking for something like that ;) I added it last night